# SQL - Update table based on select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I need to update table with values in two columns based on a condition.

So I would basically need to do the following

update columns SecurityCode and Exchange in table FundPriceDetails
where isincode = 'ES06139009N6' ,'GB00BYMT2284' ,'GB00BYNFF262')

I have the mappings of isin to Exchange in the query below.Need to add another column that will do isin to SecurityCode AS WELL

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT 'ES06139009N6' AS lsin, 'MAD' AS col2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'GB0002634946', 'LSE' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'SG1L01001701', 'SGX'
     ) x JOIN
     FundPriceDetails fpd
     ON fpd.lsin = x.lsin;
```

How would update the table with these values

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
    FundPriceDetails 
SET
    FundPriceDetails .col1 = value,
    FundPriceDetails .col2 = value
FROM
    FundPriceDetails
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT 'ES06139009N6' AS lsin, 'MAD' AS col2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'GB0002634946', 'LSE' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'SG1L01001701', 'SGX'
     ) x 
ON
    FundPriceDetails.lsin = x.lsin;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  FundPriceDetails
 SET     SecurityCode = value,
        Exchange  = value
 WHERE   isincode in('ES06139009N6' ,'GB00BYMT2284' ,'GB00BYNFF262')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I assume you meant:

```
with myData (lsin, col2) as 
(
SELECT 'ES06139009N6', 'MAD' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'GB0002634946', 'LSE' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'SG1L01001701', 'SGX'
) 
update FundPriceDetails
set blahblahColumn = x.col2 
from myData x
where FundPriceDetails.lsin = x.lsin;
```